# One bibliography for multiple .tex files

Tags: bibliographies, bibitem

I am writing my Master Thesis which consists of multiple (long) chapters, which I prefer to separate in multiple .tex files.
However, I want one bibliography which contains the references of all my separate chapters.
Currently, I am using

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{}
\end{thebibliography}
```

However, the citations in the text show up as [?], probably because the bibliography is in a separate .tex file.

I tried to create a reference.bib file with my references as well. In my separate .tex files in which I want to cite, I then used *\bibliography{reference}* to 'load' the references in this file. However, this command does also display the bibliography at the end of the separate .tex file. I do not want this, since I want a single bibliography at the end of my Thesis.

**So my question is:
How can I create one single bibliography at the end of my Thesis that consists of the references I used in separate .tex files, without displaying the bibliography in every seperate .tex file?**

Thanks!

Bas

A dummy code:

Mainfile:

```
\documentclass{dissertation}
\begin{document}

\include{1Introduction/Introduction}
\include{7Bibliography/bibliography}

\end{document}
```

'Introduction' file:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{Introduction}

I want to cite this \cite{example}.
% \bibliography{dissertation} % This shows the bibliography at the end of the introduction, whereas I want it at the end of the complete document..
```

Option 1: Bibliography using bibitem

```
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\label{bibliography}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{example} test

\end{thebibliography}
```

Option 2: reference.bib file

```
@ARTICLE{example,
  author = {Einstein, A.},
  title = {Eine neue Bestimmung der Molek\"uldimensionen},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  year = {1906},
  volume = {324},
  pages = {289--306},
  number = {2},
  doi = {10.1002/andp.19063240204},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19063240204}
}
```

Comment: splitting your text in various tex files normally works fine and shouldn't make any difference. Simply put the \bibliography at the place where you want the printed bibliography.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried that, but the citations still show up as [?] in the text..

Comment: run biblatex before compiling ?

Comment: with class book the bibitem option works fine, but who knows what your dissertation.cls is doing. For the second option: move the `\bibliography{dissertation} ` to the place where you want it.

Comment: Off-topic: The `\chapter*{Bibliography} ... \label{bibliography}` approach cannot possibly succeed in creating a valid cross-reference to the unnumbered chapter named "Bibliography". Why not? LaTeX's `\label` mechanism works (with very few exceptions) by creating an association between the label and the most recently incremented counter variable, where the incrementing is done via `\refstepcounter`. But since `\chapter*`, by construction, does not increment the counter variable called `chapter`, the subsequent `\label` directive will not create a usable association with the chapter header.

Answer (score 4):

Does that solve your problem?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Introduction.tex}
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{Introduction}
I want to cite this \cite{example}.
% \bibliography{dissertation} % This shows the bibliography at the end of the introduction, whereas I want it at the end of the complete document..
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{reference.bib}
@ARTICLE{example,
  author = {Einstein, A.},
  title = {Eine neue Bestimmung der Molek\"uldimensionen},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  year = {1906},
  volume = {324},
  pages = {289--306},
  number = {2},
  doi = {10.1002/andp.19063240204 Add to Citavi project by DOI},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19063240204 Add to Citavi project by DOI}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{reference.bib} 

\begin{document}
\input{Introduction.tex}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```